Path PNG photo on rectangle arena in Webots *HELP*
i have a png file which is the picturre of a path i drew in photoshop, i made the canva size in photoshop 5000*7000 milimeters, (i changed the scale from pixels to milimeter in photoshop)
now i want to make this photo the path of my rectantagle arena in webots so that my robot will be able to follow the line, i follow the guide below:
1- i make a rectangle arena and i make it 5*7m in size
2- i convert the rectangle arena to a base node
3- in ( solid "rectangle arena" > children > solid "floor" > children > shape > appearance PBRAppearance > baseColorMap ImageTexture > url ) i choose the path of my image
*i followed this tutorial: https://youtu.be/bUo2nphq8IQ?si=cmXdNP4Q7eqiUOaQ
the background of my rectangle arena changes into white (as expected) but i cant find the right scale in textureTransform part, i cant see the path (black line i drew on white background) on the rectangle arena.
i change the scale from 0.0000000001 to 1000000000 but nothing seems to be right, what should i do?
